# Define Haxes Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I got this issue: I've a defined sheet filled with datas organized in column. I have to graph just some of the columns into an embedded chart. I have no problems to graph the series and define to vertical axis. My problem is that I do not know how to define and show the values of the horizzontal axis. The values of this axes are in one of the column of the sheet (the values are some dates). I've tried several options but all totally useless. Below the code to figure out what's the point.
Any idea is accepted!
Thank you all in advance!

````
function myFunction() {
 var FoglioAttivo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var NomeFoglioAttivo = FoglioAttivo.getName();
 var SettedValue = FoglioAttivo.getRange("T2").setValue(NomeFoglioAttivo);
 

 var TotCons = FoglioAttivo.getRange("P1:P");
 var TotRiemp = FoglioAttivo.getRange("R1:R");
 var Livello = FoglioAttivo.getRange("E1:E");
 var Intervallo = FoglioAttivo.getRange("K1:K");
 var FirstValue = Intervallo.getValues()[1][0];
 var chartBuilder = FoglioAttivo.newChart();
 chartBuilder
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COMBO)
     .addRange(TotCons)
     .addRange(TotRiemp)
     .addRange(Livello)
     .setOption('series',{
     0:{type: 'area', color: 'blue',labelInLegend: 'Totalizzazione Consumi Lt'},
     1:{type: 'area', color: 'red', labelInLegend: 'Totalizzazione Riempimenti Lt'},
     2:{type: 'line', color: 'green', targetAxisIndex: 1, labelInLegend: 'Livello Lt'},
     } )
     .setOption('vAxes', {
     0: { title:'Tot Lt', orientation:'vertical', fontSize: 20},
     1: { title:'Lt', orientation:'vertical', fontSize: 20 },
     })
     .setOption('hAxis',{
     title: 'Intervallo', orientation:'vertical', chxr: Intervallo},)  
     .setPosition(3,20,0,0)
     ;  
     FoglioAttivo.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found the proper way. I was so close!
Below the working code!
I had simply to create a new range and define it as domanin!

````
function GeneraGrafico() {
  var FoglioAttivo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var NomeFoglioAttivo = FoglioAttivo.getName();
  var SettedValue = FoglioAttivo.getRange("T2").setValue(NomeFoglioAttivo);
  
 
  var TotCons = FoglioAttivo.getRange("P1:P");
  var TotRiemp = FoglioAttivo.getRange("R1:R");
  var Livello = FoglioAttivo.getRange("E1:E");
  var Intervallo = FoglioAttivo.getRange("K1:K");
  var FirstValue = Intervallo.getValues()[1][0];
  var chartBuilder = FoglioAttivo.newChart();
  chartBuilder
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COMBO)
      .addRange(Intervallo)
      .addRange(TotCons)
      .addRange(TotRiemp)
      .addRange(Livello)
      .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
      .setOption('series',{
      0:{type: 'area', color: 'blue',labelInLegend: 'Totalizzazione Consumi Lt'},
      1:{type: 'area', color: 'red', labelInLegend: 'Totalizzazione Riempimenti Lt'},
      2:{type: 'line', color: 'green', targetAxisIndex: 1, labelInLegend: 'Livello Lt'},
      } )
      .setOption('vAxes', {
      0: { title:'Tot Lt', orientation:'vertical', fontSize: 20},
      1: { title:'Lt', orientation:'vertical', fontSize: 20 },
      })
      .setOption('hAxis',{
      title: 'Intervallo', orientation:'vertical'},
     
            )  
      .setPosition(3,20,0,0)
      ;
           
      FoglioAttivo.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
 
  
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

#### Another solution

While you seem to have fixed this yourself, here is another solution for you.

It seems that the `vAxis` and `hAxis` use different syntax, for me, this worked:

```js
chartBuilder.addRange(range)
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)

// VERTICAL AXES
  .setOption('vAxes', {
    0: {title: "VAXES"},
    })

// HORIZONTAL AXES
  .setOption("hAxis.title", "HAXES") // Note the object notation to get the the title!


  .setPosition(5,5,0,0);
```

#### References

- [Apps Script ChartBuilder Page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder)
- [setOption](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#setoptionoption,-value)
- [Combo Chart Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart#configuration-options)